# how to execute a javascript function returned from ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function which i want to execute when ajax makes a successful request but it doesn't execute here my jquery part

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
     url: "https://www.example.com/create_chat.php",  
     data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function() 
            {
                $("#loading_indicator").show();
            },  
        success: function(response)
            {
                $(".example").html(response);

            }
        });
```

here is the response from php file

```
<script>start_chat(); alert("testing");</script>
```

i tried adding this also

```
$(".example").find("script").each(function(i) {
eval($(this).text());
});
```

but nothing works

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to execute the javascript function which i received from ajax response

Comment: simply adding start_chat(); alert("testing"); inside ajax success function wouldn't it do the work?

Comment: @PeterDarmis it's not executing

Comment: @SagarSingh all the functions start_chat etc you want to use must be located in the same page where the ajax call is made. Do you get an error start_chat undefined in console?

Comment: you don't need to put script into DOM. `a = 'start_chat(); alert("testing")'; eval(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response from create_chat could indicate which function will be used. For example

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
     url: "https://www.example.com/create_chat.php",  
     data: {
      dataString: dataString
    },
        beforeSend: function() 
            {
                $("#loading_indicator").show();
            },  
        success: function(response) // response could be 1,2,3,4.. etc
            {
                if(response==1) {
                start_chat();
                }
                if(response==2) {
                stop_chat();
                }
                if(response==3) {
                change_chat_room();
                }
                ...
                $(".example").html(response);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are work arounds, you should never be executing the response of an Ajax call directly.

> "Scripts in the resulting document tree will not be executed,
>   resources referenced will not be loaded and no associated XSLT will be
>   applied."

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#document-response-entity-body

Best practice is to respond with data, typically in the form of JSON, JSONP or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'dataString': dataString
    },
    url: 'https://www.example.com/create_chat.php',
    success: function(data) {
      start_chat();
      alert('Success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert('failed');
    }
  });
```

Comment: What about `start_chat();` ?